# PHP mailer not sending email data not inserting into mysql data base

Tags: php, mysql, phpmailer

Data is being submitted to this php file but its not storing into database I am using xampp server and I have commented $mail->sendmail as it was showing an error after I am not getting any error and getting as 'message sent' but not getting any mail.

```
require 'phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php';
$name=$_REQUEST['name'];
$desig=$_REQUEST['designation'];
$org=$_REQUEST['organisation'];
$int=$_REQUEST['interest'];
$email=$_REQUEST['email'];
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
} else {

$fname=$_FILES["file"]["name"]; 
}

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","xxxx","pccctsg");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `pccctsg`.`authors` ( `Name`, `Organisation`,  `Designation`, `Intrests`, `Email`, `File name`) VALUES ('$name, '$org', '$desig', '$int', '$int', '$fname')')");

try {
$mail = new PHPMailer(true); //New instance, with exceptions enabled

$body="hello";
$mail->IsSMTP();                           // tell the class to use SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Port       = xxx;                    // set the SMTP server port
$mail->Host       = "mail.pccctsg-conf.org"; // SMTP server
$mail->Username   = "xxxxx";     // SMTP server username
$mail->Password   = "xxxx";            // SMTP server password
$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]); 
//$mail->IsSendmail();  // tell the class to use Sendmail

//$mail->AddReplyTo("name@domain.com","First Last");

$mail->From       = "akhil@pccctsg-conf.org";
$mail->FromName   = "PCCCTSG Mailer";

$to = "akhildar@gmail.com";

$mail->AddAddress($to);

$mail->Subject  = "Registered author details";

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test
$mail->WordWrap   = 80; // set word wrap

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML

$mail->Send();
echo 'Message has been sent.';
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
    echo $e->errorMessage();
}
mysqli_close($con);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have a typo:

change

```
...VALUES ('$name, '$org', '$desig', '$int', '$int', '$fname')')");
```

into

```
...VALUES ('$name', '$org', '$desig', '$int', '$int', '$fname')");
```

(add a single quote after $name and remove the final **')**)

You can catch errors thrown by executing the query using `die()`:

```
mysql_query($con, '...') or die ('error: '. mysqli_error($con));
```

Comment: No its not working actually as its an error php should show it but am not getting any error @Reinder Wit

Comment: Thank you very much I figured it out actually I missed single quote after $name. Now everything is working :)

Answer (score 0):

Please,change mysql query:

```
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO 
`pccctsg`.`authors` ( `Name`, `Organisation`,  `Designation`, 
`Intrests`, `Email`, `File name`) 
VALUES ('$name, '$org', '$desig', '$int', '$int', '$fname')");
```

Comment: Please, try with change a code, and let me your status